# About the visitor statictics that ExpressionEngine gives

Tags: members

Ok, as all knows, there is issues with the last visit-info. That has been there long time, but now i have monitored the real-time statistics also. And what i found, that there is something in that also. Site says that it has about 50-60% more current visitors than Google Analytics. So that make me wonder, how i can trust to any of these infos.

So, what all you have to do, that system itself stops from tracking visitors and such? I just dont find this feature reliable anymore since logs doesnt match at all.

In simple: is or isnt there a way to totally stop tracking? It might and will also speed up the site if i just can stop all activity when it comes to tracking, and i dont find it nice either to tell wrong infos to members when they access to site that says "56 users logged in" but the real number is more like 8....

Thanks for any ideas that you might have.

Comment: Ian's answer is correct, but you should also know, that Google Analytics (GA) and EE tracking, track two different things. Most stats applications do. EE tracks article hits, not visitors. While EE does some work to weed out bot traffic, it's not GA. GA focuses on visitors then visitors actions. Comparison wise, you could (but I don't recommend) look at your Apache logs, which tracks pure hits, which can mean multiple counts per page, since images, javascript, etc are all pulled separately.

Comment: Ok, but the "online users" are still way too positive that EE pulls out. When i have monitored this feature on my forums, forums stats says something like "5 logged in users - 2 anonymous - 110 guests". And the guest-part is something that makes me wonder cos it sure does not give out  the right info. Or then i miss something like duration of the time that is tracked by EE, (lets say it tracks those visitores in forum in the last 60mins by default or so...).

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't use Google Analytics. I'm just saying that you should understand that the metrics are different. For example, 110 guest could mean 85 bots that EE couldn't filter, plus 25 actual people. Google has way more power to better determine bot (search engine to spammer) traffic versus actual human. So your numbers should be lower, but closer to accurate.

Comment: Ok, now i understand. Is there a way to pass Google and such from tracking?

Comment: Like Ian said, you can turn EE tracking off. Get a copy of CP Analytics to view basic Google stats from the control panel, then only have to login to GA for realtime, specific details, or reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off all track from Admin > Security & Privacy > Tracking preferences. From here you can choose to turn off template tracking, online user tracking and channel entry tracking.

On high traffic sites this could help to improve performance but in most cases it probably wont make too much difference.

Comment: Yes, correct. Forgot to look from there, thanks.

Comment: If you wanted to you can also set these as configuration variables in your config.php file so you can easily apply to new installs or server migrations.